# QR factorization: Givens rotations vs. Householder reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Here is the algorithm for Housholder $QR$ factorization:

$A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $m$ is greater than $n$.

$For \quad k=1 \quad to \quad n$

$\quad x = A_{k:m,k}$

$\quad v_{k} = sign(x_{1})||x||_{2}e_{1} + x$

$\quad v_{k} =\frac {v_{k}} {||v_{k}||_2}$

$\quad A_{k:m,k:n}= A_{k:m,k:n} - 2v_{k}( v_{k}^{*} A_{k:m,k:n})$

$End$

Then the following code is a $QR$ factorization algorithm and it is analog to algorithm above but it uses the rotation matrices $F$ and $J$ instead of Householder reflections.
$$F = \begin{bmatrix}-c&s \\ s&c \end{bmatrix}$$
 $$J= \begin{bmatrix}c&s\\ -s&c \end{bmatrix}$$ 
$$s = sin(\theta)$$
$$c = cos(\theta)$$
$\theta$ is the angle between a vector and $x$-axis.

$For \quad j=1:n$

$\quad For \quad i=m:-1:j+1$

$\quad \quad a = A(i-1,j) $

$\quad \quad b =A(i,j)$

$\quad \quad c = \frac{a}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}  %  c = cos(\theta)$

$\quad \quad s = \frac{b}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}  %  s = sin(\theta)$

$\quad \quad A(i-1:i,j:n)=\begin{bmatrix}c&-s \\ s&c \end{bmatrix}*A(i-1:i,j:n);$

$\quad End$

$End$

I cannot really follow the logic of the second algorithm. How it is mapped to the first algorithm or even $QR$ factorization?
Does anyone have any insights?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the Francis algorithm for which there is an abundant litterature. See for example (http://www.dm.unibo.it/~guerrini/html/an_09_10/QR_50_years_later.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the name.

Comment: See also [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. I am  actually working on Given rotation in Matrix Computation book. Trying to understand.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. I understood better. The link was helpful.

Comment: The short answer is a Givens rotation allows us to zero out one entry below the diagonal, while a Householder reflection can zero out all the subdiagonal entries in a column.  If it would be of interest, I can sketch out some of the trade-offs in using one approach vs. the other in an Answer.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you very much.  I am interested. I would appreciate it if you could post it anytime.